# Setting RelatedContentLinkListItemIntegerId on SingleTask doesn't work

Tags: workflow-manager

Setting `RelatedContentLinkListItemIntegerId` doesn't appear to have any impact on `SingleTask`. When I open the task in task list in SharePoint UI it shows original related item - the one on which the workflow was started, not the one I have set.

I didn't find solution to this problem anywhere so I'm posting a solution in case any one needs it in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to delete `SingleTask.RelatedContentLinkListItemId` child element in worlfow markup.

More details on my own blog http://slavensemper.blogspot.hr/2016/12/setting-related-item-on-sharepoint-2013.html.

Comment: I just added a notion that this is your own blog, so no other moderator come by and have an opinion about it :) - Nice Post!

Comment: @BennySkogberg no worries :)